# Use Dictionary for Table Data Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary, swift4

I've a dictionary that changes dependent on the user's selected options. It could be for example:

["Item1": 7, "Item2": 4, "Item3": 4, "Item4": 7, "Item5": 6]

The number next to each Item is the count for each item. I want to know how I can convert this dictionary into a table? So in the left hand column is the item and in the right hand column is the item count?

What's the best way to do this?

The data is originally an array with format: `["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item1", "Item1", "Item2"]`.

But I used

`var counts: [String: Int] = [:] , myArray.forEach { counts[$0, default: 0] += 1 }`

to count each item in the array

Comment: What array? So far you've posted a dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, changed to dictionary.

Comment: What order would the table use? Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Hm, I will need to think about this. The data is originally an array with format:

["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item1", "Item1", "Item2".  But I used var counts: [String: Int] = [:] ,  myArray.forEach { counts[$0, default: 0] += 1 }
  to count each item in the array which puts it into a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform your dictionary into a sorted array like this:

```
let array = data.map { $0 }.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
```

This will result in an array of `(key: String, value: Int)` sorted alphabetically by the keys.

Now, in your tableView delegate methods you can return `array.count` to get the number, and if you want to configure your cell you can do something like this:

```
let element = array[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel.text = element.key
cell.detailLabel.text = "\(element.value)"
```

Answer (score 1):

So, for a tableview data source, you want an array.

```
var dic = ["Item1": 7, "Item2": 4, "Item3": 4, "Item4": 7, "Item5": 6]
var tableInfo = [(String, Int)]()

for (k, v) in dic {
    let temp = (k, v)
    tableInfo.append(temp)
}
```

Revised per OP's comments.

Now you have an array of tuples suitable for sorting and use in your tableview delegate.

Comment: I want to display a table view in a view controller which has the data in, not just print it to the console

Comment: You can add two labels, one aligned left, one aligned right, and display the keys in the left label and the values on the right one. Note that UITableView does not support multiple columns, so this is just a workaround.